# Update single item in RecyclerView with DiffUtil

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'd like to update a single item in my RecyclerView. The item is just POJO bean that holds `isFavourite` flag. User can click on item and set/unset as favourite. I have implemented adater with DiffUtil callback. There is one callback method `boolean areContentsTheSame (int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)` but in my case old and new item is the same object so there is nothing to compare ( equals method returns true). Should I save previous flag value and then check for changes or is any simple solution?

Comment: What is DiffUtil?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find solution for that ?

Comment: Finally, I create new item object and replace it in the object list. Have a look here: https://android.jlelse.eu/collection-binding-with-diffutil-and-mvvm-in-android-233247e23513

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution. I don't use DiffUtil instead of I use notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload). payload variable contains data that you want to update. Please refer below code:

```
public void updateMedication(MedicationRecord medication) {
    int index = mData.indexOf(medication);
    notifyItemChanged(index);

    Bundle diffPayLoad = new Bundle();
    diffPayLoad.putInt("notify", medication.getNotify());
    notifyItemChanged(index, diffPayLoad);
}
```

In RecyclerView.Adapter, add this function to handle the payload

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SharedMedVH holder, 
                             int position, 
                             @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    } else {
        Bundle o = (Bundle) payloads.get(0);
        for (String key : o.keySet()) {
            if (key.equals("notify")) {
                holder.updateNotify(o.getInt("notify"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```